# How to submit searching field with android keyboard?

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a problem with submitting searching field with android keyboard in Appium (selenium, java).I didn't find any working solution and stuck at this point. Please, help me.

I tried this:
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().keyboard().buttons()['Done\'].tap()");

But had an error:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: post some code whatever you have stuck at

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     List<WebElement> textField = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
     textField.get(0).sendKeys("text");

Comment: and after this i should submit text with android keyboard

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute JS code that way in appium unless you are in a web view.

For hitting the search key, I would do it like this:
`driver.sendKeyEvent(IOSKeyCode.ENTER);`

Comment: i work with android, not ios. Please, tell me how can i do this for android?

Comment: same for Android :) use AndroidKeyCode

Answer (score 1):

You can send ENTER using:

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(66); // "66 - KEYCODE_ENTER
```

This link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

will give you a list of all the Android KeyEvents, if you click on one of them you can see the actual code for it, like here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are automating mobile web apps, then following is the best way to hide keyboard.

```
Map<String, Object> BackspaceKeyEvent  = new HashMap<>();
BackspaceKeyEvent.put("key", "67");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile:key:event", BackspaceKeyEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution in JavaScript worked for me:

**Java:**

```
driver.executeScript("mobile: performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "search"));
```

**Javascript:**

```
await driver.execute('mobile: performEditorAction', { action: 'search' });
```

**Notice:** This special native api just worked for Android.

This allowed me to submit a search command (same as clicking the search icon in the keyboard).

See http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/ for details on "mobile: performEditorAction".